# Mapping Service Class with two Class to DTO Class with properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I have a service Class list with two Class inside:

```
public class ParentClass
{
   public ChildClass A { get; set; }
   public ChildClass2 B { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass2 
{
   public string Color { get; set; }
   public string Nick { get; set; }
}
```

And I would want mapping with `AutoMapper` into list that have the same properties that Child's Class:

```
public class DTOClass 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Color { get; set; }
   public string Nick { get; set; }
}
```

It work fine:

My config:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ChildClass, DTOClass>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ChildClass2, DTOClass>();
```

My code:

```
List<ParentClass> listParentClass = getListParentClass();
List<DTOClass> listDtoClass = new List<DTOClass>();
ParentClass dtoClass = new ParentClass();

foreach (var parentClass in listParentClass)
{
    dtoClass = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ChildClass, DTOClass >(parentClass.A);
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ChildClass2, DTOClass >(parentClass.B, dtoClass);

    listDtoClass.Add(dtoClass);
}
```

Would I like to remove the foreach, can I?
I searched about Mapping with Child's Class, Mapping with multiple Class to one Class, no success.
I tried configurate it with `ForAllMembers`, but not work:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentClass, DTOClass>()
.ForAllMembers(op => op.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<ChildClass, DTOClass>(s.A)));
```

I'm not especialist into `AutoMapper`, if sameone could help me. I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    public class ParentClass
    {
         public ChildClass A { get; set; }
         public ChildClass2 B { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildClass2
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Nick { get; set; }
    }

    public class DTOClass
    {
        public int AId { get; set; }
        public string AName { get; set; }
        public string BColor { get; set; }
        public string BNick { get; set; }
    }
```

Your mapping:

```
    cfg.CreateMap<ChildClass, DTOClass>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ChildClass2, DTOClass>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ParentClass, DTOClass>();
```

Your example:

```
    List<ParentClass> listParentClass = getListParentClass();
    //List<DTOClass> listDtoClass = new List<DTOClass>();
    var listDtoClass = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<DTOClass>>(listParentClass);
```